# How to change the background of tabitem by using trigger in xaml?

Tags: wpf

**Here is my Xaml code**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SimpleTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <!--<Setter Property = "TabStripPlacement" Value = "Top"/>-->
            <Setter Property = "Background" Value= "Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TabItem.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>


                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>

                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="White" Height="1000"  Width="auto" IsEnabled="True">
        <TabControl Name="MainTab" Background="LightGray" SelectionChanged="MainTab_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>

            <TabItem Header="Input" x:Name="tabAlert1" Style="{StaticResource SimpleTabControl}" MouseEnter="TabItem_Enter" MouseLeave="TabItem_Leave" MouseDoubleClick="TabItem_Click" >

                <!--<TabItem.Header>
                    <Border Padding="0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="40" Margin="0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="Input" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </TabItem.Header>-->
                <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Analysis" x:Name="tabAlert2"  Style="{StaticResource SimpleTabControl}" />
            <TabItem Header="Action???" x:Name="tabAlert3" Style="{StaticResource SimpleTabControl}"/>
        </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I don't know for some reason the  trigger for isMouseOver is not triggering the back ground color change Change for Tab Item.

I have also tried the c# , code behind way , but with no success, but if change the foreground  property, it works, but not he Background property.

**Here is my C# Way**

```
private void TabItem_Enter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //var tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        //tabAlert2.Background = Brushes.Red;
        //tabItem.Background = Brushes.Green;
        var tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        tabItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

    }
```

I have Bound the mouse enter  event to tab Item.this is very basic but am frustrated this not working?Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you want to change the color of the Header?

If so, you can change the header template, try this code and if it works for you, add your other properties.

```
<Window.Resources>     
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Grid Name="Panel">
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    ContentSource="Header" 
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="MainTab">
        <TabItem Header="Input" x:Name="tabAlert1"/>
        <TabItem Header="Analysis" x:Name="tabAlert2"/>
        <TabItem Header="Action???" x:Name="tabAlert3"/>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

(Mouse is over second tab)
[image: Mouse is over second tab]

Comment: Hi ATM,  the above works fine,but can u just explain me what was wrong with my method and sherdan's method, u have used control template and Border element, any specific reason?? Please elaborate?

Comment: This msdn [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: "Controls in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) have a ControlTemplate that contains the visual tree of that control. You can change the structure and appearance of a control by modifying the ControlTemplate of that control. There is no way to replace only part of the visual tree of a control; to change the visual tree of a control you must set the Template property of the control to its new and complete ControlTemplate."

Comment: About the border I took it from this [site](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/styling-the-tabitems)